# Android Content Provider vs. SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider

I have several apps that give the best user experience when my server knows that it's the same user across apps. To verify who the user is, each user has a user_token string that is sent to my server when the app is loaded.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to share this string across apps. It seems like Content Provider is the best way to share data between apps, but a SQLite database seems a little overkill for storing/retrieving a string.

I asked this same question on an Android-Dev IRC and it was recommended that I use SharedPreferences for this - but in looking through some other SO posts on this, that's not recommended to do.

What would be the best way to do this? If it's the content provider, any idea what kind of data structure I should use for storing the string?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your apps are not sharing a process then a `SharedPreference` is not a good idea.  It is not multi-process safe.  `ContentProviders` were constructed for this purpose: sharing data between apps.  You can create your own `ContentProvider` which stores the data with a `SharedPreference`, you don't have to use SQLite.  The `ContentProvider` APIs are well suited for SQL type implementations, but it is not a requirement.

Comment: I had no idea you could create a ContentProvider to store data with a SharedPreference! Do you know if there are any tutorials or examples of such an implementation that I could check out?

Comment: @TomHammond, I don't know of a sample offhand, though it gives me a good blog post to write in the near future.  :-)  That being said, if you want to see an alternative for backing a `ContentProvider` with something other than a SQLite database, check the SDK sample code's API demos area.  In API 19 samples it is in the legacy tree within the samples.  Look for `FileProvider.java`.  This is a `ContentProvider` which uses a simple file to store its data rather than a database.

Comment: Awesome, I'll check it out. I don't think I've been to your blog before - do you have a link? I'd love to check that out as well!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what my onCreate method in the content provider looks like (which exposes the sharedprefs to the two apps):

```
@Override
    public synchronized boolean onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences sp = getContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "SurveyMeSharedPreferences", getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        String apiKey = sp.getString("user_auth_token", null);

        if (apiKey == null) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            try {
                apiKey = SurveyMe.checkUser();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            editor.putString("user_auth_token", apiKey);
            editor.commit();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Hey, could you post the whole ContentProvider? I'm looking to do the same thing. Use a ContentProvider that contains a SharedPreferences accessed by multiple processes in my apps.